# mySQL: Get records union from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables a car **model** and car **parts**. Both are related with a **partfitment** table whose only fields are the primary keys **modelID** and **partID**. 
I am trying to display the parts that fit the model car I selected.
The following works fine:

```
SELECT tblmodel.modelID,
       tblmodel.model,
       tblparts.part,
       tblparts.part_number,
       tblparts.description,
       tblparts.list_price
FROM   (tblmodel
        INNER JOIN tblpartfitment
                ON tblmodel.modelID = tblpartfitment.modelID)
       INNER JOIN tblparts
               ON tblpartfitment.partID = tblparts.partID
WHERE  tblmodel.modelID = 1;
```

The **tblparts** table has the tinyint field named **universal_part**. I am trying to include all the parts that have **universal_part** = **true** in my original query.

In other words always return all parts that are universal and those that are for the modelID specified.

I tried using a union, but get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just include the logic in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT m.ModelID, m.Model, p.part, p.part_number, p.description, p.list_price
FROM tblmodel m INNER JOIN
     tblpartfitment pf
     ON m.ModelID = pf.modelID INNER JOIN
     tblparts p
     ON pf.partID = p.partID OR p.universal_part = 1
WHERE m.ModelID = 1;
```

EDIT:

You may be best off using `union`:

```
SELECT m.ModelID, m.Model, p.part, p.part_number, p.description, p.list_price
FROM tblmodel m INNER JOIN
     tblpartfitment pf
     ON m.ModelID = pf.modelID INNER JOIN
     tblparts p
     ON pf.partID = p.partID AND p.universal_part <> 1
WHERE m.ModelID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT m.ModelID, m.Model, p.part, p.part_number, p.description, p.list_price
FROM tblmodel m CROSS JOIN
     tblparts p
WHERE p.universal_part = 1;
```

Comment: Works great, but if a ModelID is'' or if a ModelID doesn't have a partfitment relation then I get no records. the universal parts should always be returned.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN tblparts` instead.